# Any open source browser GUI automation tool that will support clicking specific icons wherever they may be on the page?

Tags: windows, linux, selenium, watir, ui-automation

On either the Windows or Linux platform, is there a GUI automation tool that will open up a browser page (any browser, I don't care) and then click on every instance of a specific icon image, wherever it may be on the page and however many times it exists.

I seem to recall this ability in IBM's Rational Robot.  Is there an open source alternative for the penniless ( oh yah... and the morally superior :-) )

EDIT:

I'd like to be able to click a specific bitmap or rectangle of pixels, where ever it is on the page, even if it is in a larger image or if it appears in a flash window.  Where ever the image exists on the page, and whatever name the container or image has, click it.

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by a "specific icon image" - specific URL or only the contents (image itself), but image name and url may be different?

Comment: Please provide sample HTML. I do not understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to interact with the page as the user does.  I want to find a specific bitmap ( presumably by crawling across the entire browser gui display ) and then click it.  I want the code to be technology agnostic.  It could be a flash page, it could be html.   Just find a series of pixels and then click them.

I realize this is not efficient in comparison to manipulating some underlying HTML structure.  This may be the dumbest thing since the cue cat, but I want to know if this is possible.

Comment: So you need to iterate through all images that are on the some page, get its source and using some image recognition library identify if this image is a "required" one and then click on it.
Except of "image recognition" part everything can be done with Selenium. However most likely there are some libraries that can do this part, so this is probably is possible

Answer (score 3):

Please take a look at [sikuli.org](http://sikuli.org/).

*Also see: [**sikuli** related questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sikuli) on SO*

It uses image-based screenshot recognition and has an integrated script editor that allows you to insert target button images directly inline with the script.

It runs on Windows and Mac OS, and will work with any applications (browsers included).

The scripting language is Jython.

The library is open source with MIT license. Actually, it is developed at MIT.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Watir](http://watir.com/)? It's a browser-based web application automation framework written in Ruby.

Comment: I'm aware of both Watir and Selenium.  I just don't know if either will find a part of web page with a specific graphic.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the image url, use this selenium selector:

```
"dom:var elist=document.getElementsByTagName('img');var toret = null;
for (var i=0; i<elist.length; i++) { if (elist[i].src=='something.png') {
toret = elist[i]; } }; toret"
```

http://seleniumhq.org/docs/04_selenese_commands.html#locating-by-dom

Answer (score 1):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/downloads.shtml) is another great tool for automation. You could check the User Defined Function (UDF) for IE, which comes as a part of default package.

It provides a whole lot automation IE Management, Windows System level management, Sound Management etc.,

You could start by downloading the no-install package http://www.autoitscript.com/cgi-bin/getfile.pl?autoit3/autoit-v3-sfx.exe and look into the examples of IE Management UDF in the UDFs3.chm help file.

Answer (score 0):

If your image is identifiable on the page by a CSS id, you should be able to accomplish this using [cucumber/webrat](http://cukes.info/) and/or cucumber/selenium (the latter if you also want to test javascript in the page). Not a GUI tool but very powerful.

Comment: How do you expect to specify the graphic? Do you have control over the web pages that you want to target?

Comment: I don't have control over the graphic.  I can give it a bitmap to look for, though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO: there is not an open source tool that does this. That is because this is a bad idea. Commercial tools like Rational tried to do this because they tried to be all things to all people (even if they didn't work very well). But selecting by bitmap image is easy to think about and hard to perform reliably so none of the modern popular tools even try. Instead they focus on how to be SUCCESSFUL.

The right thing to do, as others have already said here is to select images by CSS selector or by image file name. This can be done reliably by any modern GUI test tool: Watir, Selenium, Webrat ...

Comment: I wonder why this got one upvote and one downvote.